# HighCharts PieChart with just one segment doesn't show a label

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/matellis/BLcem/

You'll see there is no label. Edit the piechart so the series has two elements like this http://jsfiddle.net/matellis/Egqeg/ and the labels reappear.

Is this a bug or a feature? Have we missed some setting that says 'always show labels even when there's just one segment'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looks like it's a bug and they are already aware of it -> https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/304

Comment: Really helpful, I wondered where they kept the bug list. Thank-you.